# SHACL validation using dash:reifiableBy

Tags: rdf, topbraid-composer, shacl

I am testing validation of RDF data using SHACL in TopBraidComposer Maestro Edition (v 6.3.2).
During my analysis of SHACL, I came across the document [DASH Reification Support for SHACL](http://datashapes.org/reification.html). Chapter 2 of that document defines the property `dash:reifiableBy`, which - according to the document - "*can be used to link a SHACL property shape with one or more node shapes. Any reified statement must conform to these node shapes.*"

This appears to say that one can define SHACL validation of statements against certain shapes. The document has an example, which I try to run in TopBraidComposer - slightly modified, though, in order to actually get validation results (in this case, that a statement is invalid). The code is:

```
# baseURI: http://example.org/shacl/shapes/dash/reifiableBy
# imports: http://datashapes.org/dash
# prefix: exshacl

@prefix ex: <http://example.org/shacl/data/dash/reifiableBy#> .
@prefix exschema: <http://example.org/shacl/schema/dash/reifiableBy/> .
@prefix exshacl: <http://example.org/shacl/shapes/dash/reifiableBy#> .
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://example.org/shacl/shapes/dash/reifiableBy>
  a owl:Ontology ;
  owl:imports <http://datashapes.org/dash> ;
.

###########################
# Shape(s)
###########################

exshacl:ProvenanceShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property [
        a sh:PropertyShape ;
        sh:path exschema:date ;
        sh:datatype xsd:date ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        a sh:PropertyShape ;
        sh:path exschema:author ;
        sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
    ] ;
.

exshacl:PersonShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass exschema:Person ;
    sh:property [
        a sh:PropertyShape ;
        sh:path exschema:age ;
        sh:datatype xsd:integer ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        dash:reifiableBy exshacl:ProvenanceShape ; 
    ] ;
.

###########################
# Data
###########################

ex:Bob 
    a exschema:Person ;
    exschema:age "23"^^xsd:integer ;
.
    
ex:BobAge23Reification
    a rdf:Statement ;
    rdf:subject ex:Bob ;
    rdf:predicate exschema:age ;
    rdf:object "23"^^xsd:integer ;
    ex:author ex:Claire .
```

The `exshacl:PersonShape` works, in so far as the property shape ensures that `exschema:age` is present for a `exschema:Person` and has datatype `xsd:integer`.

However, the rdf statement `ex:BobAge23Reification` on the triple `ex:Bob exschema:age "23"^^xsd:integer` is not validated against the `exshacl:ProvenanceShape`. While property `exschema:author` is present in the statement, property `exschema:date` is not.

**Is the example code wrong or missing a crucial bit, or does `dash:reifiableBy` not define a SHACL constraint component that is actually validated (and instead is intended only for defining editing forms in GUIs)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Such questions may be better asked on the topbraid-users mailing list)

The shape looks fine but TopBraid currently doesn't validate rdf:Statements, but instead uses reified triples using http://datashapes.org/reification.html#uriReification

This may change in future versions, depending on the direction that Jena may take for RDF* support.

The current version of TBC isn't suitable for editing such reified values, but TopBraid EDG is.